# JPA-ECLIPSELINK FUNCTION throwing error

Tags: java, jpa

I am executing the below query:-

```
select FUNCTION(LOWER,d.comp) from peopledbvo d where d.person = :persons;
```

but getting the error unexpected token [FUNCTION] internal exception, i also tried FUNC but getting the same error. here i am using FUNCTION to execute the database function LOWER.

Comment: and LOWER is a JPQL function (rather than losing datastore portability and hacking it through FUNCTION), and you don't state what happens if you used that instead ...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the LOWER function because it's part of the JPA spec:
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string

```
select LOWER(d.comp) from peopledbvo d where d.person = :persons;
```

Comment: well, i tried LOWER also but its not workimg, for this also i am getting the error unexpected token [LOWER]

Comment: Post the java code you are using to send the query to the DB.

Comment: TypedQuery<peopledbvo> query=entitymanager.createquery(query, peopledbvo.class);   and query.setparameter("persons",sarath);  List<comp> x=query.getResultList();

Comment: I think there's a problem with your config. The LOWER function is directly supported by the Eclipselink JPA implementation (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL) and it should work with no problem.